# Converting 24hr Time to 12hr Time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and have read through many of these conversion questions posted, tried to follow syntax guidelines but am really at a loss for what to do here.

My `CASE` statement successfully converts 24hr time to 12hr, the issue arises when I attempt to add a semicolon to the resulting time with the `IF` statement. The resulting `@newtime` variable produces a `NULL`, and I want it to only create one result, not two.

Running Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760 Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

```
DECLARE @current24hrtime INT;
SET @current24hrtime = 1522;
DECLARE @newtime varchar(20);

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @current24hrtime < 100
            THEN CONCAT(@current24hrtime + 1200, ' AM')
        WHEN @current24hrtime >= 100 AND @current24hrtime <= 1159
            THEN CONCAT(@current24hrtime, ' AM')
        WHEN @current24hrtime >= 1200 AND @current24hrtime <= 1259
            THEN CONCAT(@current24hrtime, ' PM')
        WHEN @current24hrtime >= 1300 AND @current24hrtime <= 2359
            THEN CONCAT(@current24hrtime - 1200, ' PM')

END;


        IF LEN(@current24hrtime) = 6
            SET @newtime = LEFT(@current24hrtime, 1) + ':' + RIGHT(@current24hrtime, 5)
        ELSE IF LEN(@current24hrtime) = 7
            SET @newtime = LEFT(@current24hrtime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@current24hrtime, 5)
SELECT @newtime;
```

Comment: Why are you dealing with time as an integer in the first place? This can be done very easily if you use the proper datatype.

Comment: The biggest challenge I see here is choosing the wrong datatype. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: If you'll permit me to think out of the box for a bit: `SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), DATEADD(MINUTE, @current24hrtime / 100 * 60 + @current24hrtime % 60, 0), 0), 7)`. If you really want the space you can `STUFF` it in there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you're a mad man, don't encourage someone taking a time and shoving it into an int field lol!

Comment: The input will be an integer, and the database is setup (not by me) to store the time as a 'varchar' and can not be changed.

Comment: @RPowers that makes me want to go crawl back into bed and forget this ever happened, yikes.

Comment: @haag1 Agreed. You'd never get out of bed if you saw the mess of a DB I'm working with here.

Comment: @haag1: a time can be stored in an `INT` field quite well, although it'd be much better to store it as the minute offset, instead of the `HHMM` digits. In SQL 2000 there's no `TIME`, and storing it as a `DATETIME` where you steadfastly ignore the date component is possible, but has its own problems.

Comment: @JeroenMostert good point, I was quickly reading and read "2000" as "2008", never worked with anything less than 2005 before, but I've seen the mess it can be though.. god speed

Comment: @JeroenMostert The problem with doing it the right way and converting to actual DATETIME, is the way the DB is setup. Time is stored as a varchar and if I change that it will break an old FoxPro program they have running. Also, stuff doesn't work with SQL 2000 if I understand correctly, that was my first attempt at making this work and it errored out every time.

Comment: one problem is that datetime is not time, which is possibly why SQL server introduced a TIME type.  SQL server still badly lacks the concept of a TimeSpan as far as I know.

Comment: Wow, you're right -- `STUFF` was only added in 2005. It seems like it's been around forever, but it hasn't been *quite* forever. I've worked with SQL Server 2000, but not for a very, very long time. I wouldn't want to anymore, either -- who could live without `STUFF`? :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert We suffer through it. Server update is a year away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also wasn't able to test in SQL Server 2000.. Change your @newtime variable to datetime, because I'm pretty sure time datatype did not exist in SQL Server 2000.

```
DECLARE @current24hrtime INT;
SET @current24hrtime = 1522;
DECLARE @newtime datetime;

SET @newtime = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @current24hrtime = 0 OR @current24hrtime = 2400 THEN '00:00'
            WHEN LEN(@current24hrtime) = 4 THEN 
                LEFT(CAST(@current24hrtime AS VARCHAR(20)),2) + ':' + RIGHT(CAST(@current24hrtime AS VARCHAR(20)),2)
            WHEN LEN(@current24hrtime) = 3 THEN
                LEFT(CAST(@current24hrtime AS VARCHAR(20)),1) + ':' + RIGHT(CAST(@current24hrtime AS VARCHAR(20)),2)
            ELSE '' --not sure how you would want to handle invalid integer times
        END

SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@newtime,100),7)) [newtime]
```

Comment: This one did the trick, clever to declare `@newtime` as `DATETIME` then convert it to a `varchar` to match the db schema. Well played.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL Server formatting

Your integer seems to be zoned HHMM, so that can be split into minutes since midnight with some maths. The number of minutes can then be added to time zero, converted to date, then the time section retained. I think this should work in SQL Server 2000:

```
DECLARE @current24hrtime as int;
SET @current24hrtime = 0;

SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(55),dateadd(minute,60 * floor(@current24hrtime / 100) + @current24hrtime % 60,cast(0 as datetime)), 100), 7));
```

Comment: The `FLOOR` is unnecessary -- this is a rare case where we're actually fine with integer division, which "takes care of this".

Comment: @JeroenMostert Without FLOOR, I had the wrong answer, I would have needed to change the order of operations in order to get int divide to work for me

Comment: however you could literally remove the letters FLOOR, and leave the brackets there, but not if someone meddled with the data-type, a bit of future proofing, just in case.

Comment: The problem is your code converts to a `DATETIME`, the column in the database is `nchar`. I can't insert `DATETIME` into that field properly.

Comment: @RPowers - it doesn't produce a datetime, it produces a varchar, the same as in your code example.  Or are you saying that the intermediate use of datetime is unavailable in SQL 2000 - I thought it was though

Comment: @Cato When it output to the table, it displayed as `DATETIME` producing `1 Jan 1990` in literally every field updated. So, I certainly could be mistaken, maybe that's what a `NULL` would display as? Like I said I'm fairly new to SQL. When I ran the code on it's own, it worked just fine which is why I initially accepted yours as the answer. However when it accepted the integer parameters from the EDI system I'm using it did not succeed. The answer provided by @JeremyWolverton above was the code I ended up using, with a few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it in 2000, but you can try.

```
SELECT @newtime = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(CAST(@current24hrtime / 100 as VARCHAR) + ':' 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@current24hrtime % 100 as VARCHAR),2) AS DATETIME)),7)
SELECT @newtime
```